# Create a Multidimensional Hash Table Array in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array, hashtable

I was wondering if there was a shorter way to create a multidimentional hashtable array in powershell. I have been able to successfully create them with a couple of lines like so.

```
$arr = @{}
$arr["David"] = @{}
$arr["David"]["TSHIRTS"] = @{}
$arr["David"]["TSHIRTS"]["SIZE"] = "M"
```

That said I was wondering if there was any way to shorten this to something like this...

```
$new_arr["Level1"]["Level2"]["Level3"] = "Test"
```

Where it would create a new level if it doesn't already exist.  Thanks!

Comment: You're after [autovivification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification) and no, PowerShell doesn't have it.

Answer (score 11):

You need to name/define the sub-levels or else the interpreter doesn't know what kind of type it's working with (array, single node, object, etc.)

```
$arr = @{
    David = @{
        TSHIRTS = @{
            SIZE = 'M'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Maximilian's answer here is a more complete example how to use a *multidimensional hashtable*:

```
$acls = @{
Ordner1 = @{
    lesen     = 'torsten', 'timo';
    schreiben = 'Matthias', 'Hubert'
};
Ordner2 = @{
    schreiben = 'Frank', 'Manfred'; 
    lesen = 'Tim', 'Tom' }
```

}

*Add data:*

```
$acls.Ordner3=@{}
$acls.Ordner3.lesen='read'
$acls.Ordner3.schreiben='write','full'
```

*Access:*

```
$acls.Ordner2.schreiben
```

**Result:**

Frank

Manfred